# Item in a List - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple function to check if both of the list hold the same items, even if they are not in the same order. For example:

```
list1 = ("a","b","c","d","e","f")

list2 = ("f","c","b","d","e","a")

if list2 == list 1 (in any order):
   print("list 1 and list 2 are similar.")

else:
    print("list 1 and list 2 are different")
```

I am trying to find out if list 2 and list 1 both hold the same items.

Comment: What about the repeated elements if there are any? I mean, what should be the result for `("a", "a", "b") and ("b", "a")`?

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: And didn't you ask this [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34438949/3001761)?

Comment: I also provided example code.

Comment: You provided *psuedo*code - this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service, some actual effort is expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what is pseudocode and I have tried to provide some of my own knowledge. I would provide better code but I am new to python and have only had it for two weeks

Comment: *"what is pseudocode"* - like your main question, you should consider Googling it before asking.

Comment: I googled it and I realised that other people do pseudocode kind of like the duplicate of this question.